# getting "expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token" on a linked list to BST constructor signature

Tags: c++

For my homework, I've got some headers files (supplied by my lecturer) with some issues. The goal - implementing the methods from the header files that dealing with BST and linked lists (building a tree from a list, a list from a tree and some other methods).

The problem: getting some errors from the signatures of the header, including:

error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
     btree(LinkedList &list);
* I don't have a clue why

error: ‘LinkedList’ does not name a type
     btree & operator=(const LinkedList & ls);
* althoght I've included the linked list header in this file

- error: ‘LinkedList’ does not name a type
   LinkedList* Tree2linkListbyDepth();

> EDIT:
>   I removed the circule including, the frind LinkedList line, and add class btree and struct node to linkedList.h.
>   I add the cpp files as well.
>   Please ignore errors at the cpp files. I know they have some mistakes. And I'm not trying to make you guys solve it for me. I'm only tring to fix the headers errors so that I can start implement the methods on the cpp files, test them and learn cpp while doing it. (This is my first cpp homework)
>
> btree h:

```
#ifndef _btree_H
#define _btree_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int key_value;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

class btree
{
friend class LinkedList;
node* root;

public:
// Default constructor
btree();
~btree();

// Copy Constructor by list
btree(LinkedList & list);
// Copy Constructor by tree
btree(btree & bt);
// assignment operator from linked list
btree & operator=(const LinkedList & ls);
// assignment operator from tree
btree& operator=(const btree &bt);
// insert new value to binary tree
void insert(int key);
// mirror the tree
void mirror();
LinkedList* Tree2linkListbyDepth();
int getTreeDepth();

// print tree (in order)
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, btree& dt);

};

#endif
```

> Linkedlist Header:

```
#ifndef _List_H
#define _List_H


#include<iostream>

class btree;
struct node;

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
Node* next;
int data;
};


class LinkedList
{
friend class btree;

public:
int length;
Node* head;
LinkedList(btree &bt);
LinkedList(LinkedList &bt);
LinkedList();
~LinkedList();
void add(int data);
LinkedList & operator=(const LinkedList & bt);
LinkedList& operator=(const btree &bt);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, LinkedList& l);
LinkedList inorder(node *bt, LinkedList *head);
Node inOrder(node *root, LinkedList *list) ; //change to private!
};

#endif
```

> btree cpp file:

```
#include "btree.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

btree::btree() { // default constructor  CHECK!
root->right = nullptr;
root->left = nullptr;
root->key_value = 0; // check if needed
}


btree::btree(LinkedList & list)
{
Node* temp = list.head;
while(temp != nullptr) {
    insert(temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
   }
}

node *newNode(int key) { // create a new node
node *temp = new node; //CHECK IF NEW IS NEEDED
temp->key_value = key;
temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
return temp;
}

node *insert(node* node, int key) {  // NEED FIXING
// If the tree is empty, return a new node
if (node == NULL)
    return newNode(key);

/* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
if (key < node->key_value)
    node->left = insert(node->left, key);
else if (key > node->key_value)
    node->right = insert(node->right, key);

/* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
return node;
}


btree::~btree() { // CHECK !
}



void inorder(node *root) { // CHECK
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d \n", root->key_value);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

// passing the root to a printing function
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, btree & dt) { // CHECK
inorder(dt.root);
return os;
}
```

> linkedlist cpp:

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "btree.h"
#include <iostream>

LinkedList::LinkedList(btree & bt) {
    LinkedList *list = new LinkedList;
    inOrder(bt.root, list);

}

Node inOrder(node *root, LinkedList *list) { // CHECK
    if (root->key_value != NULL) {
        inOrder(root->left, list);
        list->head->next = new Node;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        inOrder(root->right, list);
    }
}

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
head = new Node;
    head->next == NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    delete head;
}
```

Comment: `btree(LinkedList &list);` Try using a different name for your parameter. Because of `using namespace std;` it may be seeing the `std::list` class.

Comment: What's inside your `"LinkedList.h"`? Post the contents, including the `#include` directives that you have there.

Comment: just tried a different name for the list parameter, getting the same error still. I'm editing and adding the second header file.

Comment: Removing the linked list header and declaring a forward decl before class `btree` compiles fine, so you either have a likely circular inclusion or an include-guard repetition.  Unrelated, [`using namespace std;` is a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), especially in header files. And the implementation has reservation for identifiers beginning with two underscores or one underscore followed by a capital letter, so while `_btree_H` is viable, `_List_cpp` (an odd name for a header fencepost on its own) is to be avoided.

Comment: You have circular includes

Comment: Unrelated, I can't be the only one curious about where `node` comes from, when `Node` is clearly the defined class name. As near as I can see, there is no `node` by declaration *anywhere*.

Comment: @Liran A binary tree and a linked list are two totally different data structures.  Why are you trying to merge the two totally different concepts into one?  That is conceptually where everything breaks down -- it isn't really a coding issue, it seems to be a conceptual one.  You should be able to write a linked list class without any knowledge of a binary tree, and you should be able to write a binary tree class with no knowledge of a linked list.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just edit the question and add the cpp files. The node is the tree's struct and Node is the list class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know it looks wired. But it's my home assignment, part of my software engineering degree.. I've got the header files as they are from the lecturer, and I can only add private methods to the headers and inclusion. I can't change the struct, classes and signatures of the headers. My assignment is to implement the method mentioned at the header files and fix the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you code does not declare `LinkedList` before

```
btree(LinkedList &list);
```

Name lookup cannot find that name. Hence the error.

The friend declaration that you have above

```
friend class LinkedList;
```

does *not* introduce `LinkedList` as a name visible to regular name lookup.

I see that you include `LinkedList.h`. What's in there? Do you declare `LinkedList` in that header file? If so, then it might be suffering from circular inclusion problem. No way to say without seeing the contents of `LinkedList.h`.

---

Now as you posted `LinkedList.h`, it is obvious that you have circular inclusion. That's the reason for your error. You have to get rid of circular inclusion. Remove one of these `#include` directives that form circular inclusion and forward-declare the corresponding class instead.

For example:

- Remove `#include "btree.h"` from `LinkedList.h`
- Instead add forward-declarations

  ```
  struct node;
  class btree;
  ```

  to `LinkedList.h`.
- Add `#include "btree.h"` to `LinkedList.cpp`.

---

Declaring `LinkedList` as a friend to `LinkedList` is pointless.

Comment: Circular inclusion would be my guess, incredibly confusing the first time it happens to you.

Comment: just add the second header file

Comment: I removed the inclusion from the Linkedlist header and add the forward-declaration: class btree, and now I've got a different type of errors for each line that uses "node". For example:  error: ‘node’ has not been declared
     LinkedList inorder(node *bt, LinkedList *head);

Comment: and I keep getting the wired error: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
     btree(LinkedList &list);

Comment: @Liran: A forward declaration for `struct node;` in `LinkedList.h` is also needed. As for the rest... there's no way to say what's going on there without seeing the result of your recent changes.